# Prove that any composition of quotient maps is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

> Prove that any composition of quotient maps is a quotient map

**My Proof**

Let $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ be quotient maps, we show that $g \circ f : X \to Z$ is a quotient map by showing that $Z$ has the quotient topology on it induced by the map $g \circ f$, i.e. that $V \subseteq Z$ is open in $Z$ if and only if $(g \circ f)^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$

To that end pick $V$ open in $Z$ then $(g \circ f)^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$ by continuity, completing one direction.

To prove the converse we pick a saturated open set $U'$ in $X$ with respect to $g \circ f$, then $U' = (g \circ f)^{-1}[V']$ for some subset $V' \subseteq Z$, and we need to show $V'$ is open in $Z$. Now $U' = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[V']]$ and put $\Lambda = \ g^{-1}[V']$, then $U' = f^{-1}[\Lambda]$, and since $f$ is a quotient map we have $A$ open in $Y \iff f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X$, so since $U'$ is open in $X$, we have $\Lambda = \ g^{-1}[V']$ open in $Y$, and since $g$ is a quotient map we have $W$ open in $Z \iff g^{-1}[W]$ is open in $Y$, therefore $V'$ must be open in $Z$. $\square$

---

Is my proof satisfactory and rigorous enough?

Comment: Yup, this looks good! Note that since we already know composition respects continuity and bijectivity, we only really need to show that composition also respects mapping saturated open sets to open sets.

Comment: But, why does it suffice to prove that $g\circle f:X\to Z$ is a quotient map? In general, if we had $f_i:X_i\to\Y_i$, their composition is not necessarily a quotient map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine. I would maybe do it like this:

$U \subseteq Z$ open iff $g^{-1}[U] \subseteq Y$ is open as $g$ is quotient.

$g^{-1}[U] \subseteq Y$ is open iff $f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]] \subseteq X$ open as $f$ is quotient. And as $(g \circ f)^{-1}[U]= f^{-1}[g^{-1}[U]]$ we have

$U \subseteq Z$ open iff $(g \circ f)^{-1}[U]$ open, showing that $g \circ f$ is quotient.

Comment: I believe the last line should read $U\subseteq Z$ instead of $U\subseteq Y$.