# Prove that the composition of quotient functions a quotient function

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ be quotient maps. The idea is to show that the composite function $g \circ f: X \to Z$ is a quotient map. To do this, we must proof that $V^{\text{open}} \subseteq Z$ if and only if $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

For the first implication:

Let $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ be quotient maps, in particular, both continuous functions. If $V^{\text{open}} \subseteq Z$, then $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ due to the continuity of $f$ and $g$.

conversely:

Similarly, let $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ be quotient maps. Furthermore, if $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, this implies that $$(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V))$$ is open.

Since $f$ is a quotient function, it follows that $$g^{-1}(V)$$ is open.

Moreover, as $g$ is a quotient function, it must be the case that $V$ is open in $Z$

Is there anything to improve this? any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Looks good. Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326183/prove-that-any-composition-of-quotient-maps-is-a-quotient-map) and its answers too.

Comment: If you're interested mainly in feedback to your proof, you should use the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag, see also the [corresponding tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info).